# How to concatenate quote marks onto a string using Visual Code?

Tags: javascript, string

I am having a lot of trouble trying to concatenate a string together that has quote marks within it.  I am using Visual Code, which often changes what I write with regards to the quotes, and then nothing works (is there a way to tell Visual code- leave these lines alone?)

Here is the String I am trying to build:

```
lineData= lineData + 'track[' + row + '][' + col + ']=' + '"' + '"' + ';';
```

Now, when I run this code, the concatenated double quotes are gone.
What is the right way to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why is this so complex?  Perhaps not so much plus (+) since it is just a bunch of characters OR better yet use a template literal string

```
lineData= lineData + `track[${row}][${col}]="";`;
```

OR use

```
lineData= lineData + 'track[' + row + '][' + col + ']="";';
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals